# In cmd.exe with codepage 437, why are characters whose "number" is greater than 127 prepended with a ┬ when using type?

Tags: cmd.exe, character-encoding, code-page

I have a file that contains some characters whose "number" is greater than 127. If I use `type file.txt` to display the content of the file in a `cmd.exe` console whose code page (`chcp`) is set to 437, these characters are prepended with a `┬` character. I don't understand why this is and if there is a possibility to turn that off.

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia page about [codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)? It contains a lot of information about the origins.

Comment: Your text seems to be [UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Comparison_with_single-byte_encodings) encoded, try to change `chcp 65001`

Comment: @LotPings: that was indeed the case. Please turn your  comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Did you trying changing encoding to UTF8NoBom or ASCII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set) the glyph `┬` is assigned to hex 0xC2 / dec 194.

I did remember that some [UTF8 2 byte encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) start with `0xC2` so the conclusion the text is in this encoding was obvious to me.

To display UTF8 in cmd you'll need Codepage 65001

```
chcp 65001
```